# Scientists send a nuclear bomb to Mars (to study the plume by spectroscopy) but destroy the unique martian populated area

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, mars, nuclear-weapons

I used to believe that this story was part of *The Martian Chronicles* but it is not. I would love to find the author/title. Sounds a bit like Fredric Brown's ideas.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi! When did you read this? Are there any other details you could [edit] in? ([This checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) might help jog your memory)

Comment: There is a story (the name of which i do not recall) which something like, The scientists determined that Mars had no intelligent life... (and after the bomb detonated, they were right). I am guessing this is the same story.

Comment: If the correct answer is posted, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Something like this happens in Larry Niven's Known Space but it's later revealed (in "Vandevecken") to be a deliberate act.

Answer (score 37):

"[Earthmen Bearing Gifts](https://americanliterature.com/author/fredric-brown/short-story/earthmen-bearing-gifts)" by Fredric Brown

> "They will watch the flash through their lunar telescopes and get a--what do they call it?--a spectroscopic analysis. That will tell them more than they know now (or think they know; much of it is erroneous) about the atmosphere of our planet and the composition of its surface. It is--call it a sighting shot, Khee. They'll be here in person within a few oppositions. And then--"
>
> Mars was holding out, waiting for Earth to come. What was left of
> Mars, that is; this one small city of about nine hundred beings. The
> civilization of Mars was older than that of Earth, but it was a dying
> one. This was what remained of it: one city, nine hundred people

....

> "Hope it didn't kill anybody. Any Martians, that is. Rog, did it hit
> dead center in Syrtis Major?"
>
> "Near as matters. I'd say it was maybe a thousand miles off, to the
> south. And that's damn close on a fifty-million-mile shot. Willie, do
> you really think there are any Martians?"
>
> Willie thought a second and then said, "No."
>
> He was right.

Comment: this is the one i was thinking of.

Comment: They have spacecraft that can travel to Mars with humans, but their best idea is to launch a nuclear weapon and analyze the spectroscopic signature??? Then again, the US did consider bombing the Moon back then, but those were not scientists.

Comment: They hope to have manned spacecraft in a few years, but as the story is happening, humans do not yet have the capability for a manned trip to Mars.

Comment: Scientists, including young Carl Sagan, were involved in the lunar bombing project A119, which was indeed lead by USAF. There was a Cold War motivation but the idea was also to study the produced cloud of dust by spectroscopy as well as, later, the fresh crater. A bit like the Deep Impact mission on comet Tempel 1 (although the projectile was not a bomb).

Comment: Worth noting that in real life, we wildly overestimated the density of the Martian atmosphere until we got a probe on side. This forced total redesign of all Mars lander proposals.

Comment: Also interesting that missing the target by a thousand miles was seen as acceptable!

Comment: @FranckSelsis - And was this the correct answer?